# Replicate Postgres 9.2 to 9.4 with no downtime

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.2

My current set up has a database running on Postgres 9.2.4 and would like to move from AWS EC2 to RDS.  However, AWS requires Postgres be running at least Postgres 9.4 in order to perform this migration.

With the goal of minimal downtime, as this is a production-level database, I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to replicate between versions of Postgres, specifically 9.2 to 9.4.  Performing a `pg_upgrade` requires bringing the database down, and took around 25-30 minutes to complete. We're looking to have our downtime be significantly less than half an hour, if possible.

Has anyone successfully migrated from 9.2 to 9.4 with little to no downtime? Or other suggestions that may minimize how long the database must be down for?

Comment: Do you have many tables in your databases that are updated regularly? If not, you could create a temporary audit table using triggers (e.g. storing a serial, the action, table and primary key as a text array), then backup and restore the database, and finally synchronise the databases by transferring all updates via dblink until you're ready to switch the old server off and swap them. You could keep the downtime to just a few seconds that way, but it may be a lot of work.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, it's an eCommerce site, so new users, transactions / purchases... Plus our own homebrew email tracking is done in the database.  I'd say at least 12-15 tables that regularly have inserts and selects, and another 20-30 that are regularly read from, and inserted to slightly less frequently.

Comment: Unless there is something very unusual about your database, it should take far less than 25 minutes to run pg_upgrade if you use link mode (`-k`).